# Codeigniter: Getting the value of field "ID" table->generate

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to ask. How can I get the value of the field "ID" in my database table. I have this code in my model:

```
    public function select_queries($get_table){
        $this->load->library('table');
        $query = $this->db->get($get_table['ninja7']);

        $tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="tbl_allinventory">',
                      'heading_row_start' => '<tr id="tbl_allinventory_tr1">',
                      'heading_row_end' => '</tr>',
                      'row_start' => '<tr name="">',
                      'cell_start' => '<td>',
                      'cell_end' => '</td>',
                      'row_end' => '</tr>',
                      'table_close' => '</table>');
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);

        $sample_query = $this->table->generate($query);
        return $sample_query;

    }
```

Here is my view:

```
    <div class="row">
    <form action="add_all_inventory" method="POST" id="frm_add_all_inventory">
        <h3><input type='text' name="table1" id="table1" value='<?php echo $table1; ?>' style='border: none; background-color: transparent;' readonly/></h3>
        <button type="button" style='position: absolute; top:275px; right: 173px;' class='btn_addinventory btn-success btn-sm' id='btn_addinventory' name='btn_addinventory'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Add Inventory</button>
    </form>
    <div class="table_design">
        <?php echo $select1; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="edit_all_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" >
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe scrolling='0' style="width: 100%; height: 60%; border: none;" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/edit_all_views'); ?>/<?php echo $table1; ?>"></iframe>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--<input type="text" value="<?php echo $table1; ?>"/>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller:

```
    public function inventory_tables(){
        $tablenaming1 = $_POST['ninja7'];

        $this->session->userdata('login_session');
        $this->data['title'] = "Inventory";
        $this->load->vars($this->data);

        $this->load->view('homeview');

        $select_inv['inventorytype'] = $this->inventory_model->select_tables();
        $this->load->view('inventoryview', $select_inv);


        $sample['sample'] = $this->inventory_model->select_fields_2($_POST['ninja7']);
        $select_details['select'] = $this->inventory_model->select_queries($this->input->post());
        $select_details1['select2'] = $this->inventory_model->select_queries3($this->input->post());
        $value_array = array('sample1' => $sample['sample'],
                             'table1' => $tablenaming1,
                             'select1' => $select_details['select'],
                             'select3' => $select_details1['select2']);
        $this->load->view('sampleviewtable', $value_array);

        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }
```

I hope you can help me on this one. I need to get the ID because I need that as a reference when I want to update certain columns. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add the table definition

Comment: @Mikpa It is an autogenerated table from the database, all of the possible definitions are already in my question. What kind of definition do you want me to add? Or is there anything confusing about my question..